# (Angular at fault) Function member Does Not Exists After Inheritance (TypeError: row.dynamicProperties is not a function)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, inheritance, typescript

I'm running an angular / mvc website. And I separate all my model and stuff.
At some point I feel need of an extra property which is not part of my model. I though of inheritance and start writing codes.
first I went with 'getter', seeing it's get override simply, I though about something more supported by intellisense like method, so one won't simply override it without thinking.

here what I write:

```
/**
 * Created by Hassan on 4/4/2016.
 */
abstract class DynamicPropertiesProvider {
    private _dynamicProperties:Object;

    constructor() {
        this._dynamicProperties = {};
    }

    dynamicProperties():Object {
        return this._dynamicProperties;
    }
}
```

and then i use it in my model like:

```
/**
 * Created by Hassan on 3/16/2016.
 */

///<reference path="dynamicPropertiesProvider.ts"/>
class AcDocRow extends DynamicPropertiesProvider{
    public FinYear: string;
    public DocNoTemp: number;
    public DocRow: number;
    public HsbCod: string;
    public RowDsc: string;
    public Bedehkar: number;
    public Bestankar: number;
    public Bookmark: boolean;
    public MainDocNo: number;
    public DocDate: string;

    //Getters And Setters
    get CompositeKey():string {
        return this.FinYear + "-" + this.DocNoTemp + "-" + this.DocRow;
    }

    get Date():string {
        return ((this.DocDate) ? this.DocDate.substr(0, 4) + "/" + this.DocDate.substr(4, 2) + "/" + this.DocDate.substr(6, 2) : "");
    }

    constructor(finYear, docNoTemp, docRow, hsbCod, rowDsc, bedehkar, bestankar, bookmark, mainDocNo, docDate){
        super(); //Call Super (Parent) Class Constructor
        this.setup();
        if (finYear != undefined) this.FinYear = finYear;
        if (docNoTemp != undefined) this.DocNoTemp = docNoTemp;
        if (docRow != undefined) this.DocRow = docRow;
        if (hsbCod != undefined) this.HsbCod = hsbCod;
        if (rowDsc != undefined) this.RowDsc= rowDsc;
        if (bedehkar != undefined) this.Bedehkar = bedehkar;
        if (bestankar != undefined) this.Bestankar= bestankar;
        if (bookmark != undefined) this.Bookmark = bookmark;
        if (mainDocNo != undefined) this.MainDocNo= mainDocNo;
        if (docDate != undefined) this.DocDate= docDate;
    }

    private setup():void{
        this.FinYear = "";
        this.DocNoTemp = 0;
        this.DocRow = 0;
        this.HsbCod = "";
        this.RowDsc = "";
        this.Bedehkar = 0;
        this.Bestankar = 0;
        this.Bookmark = false;
        this.MainDocNo = 0;
        this.DocDate = "";
    }

    public copy():AcDocRow{
        return new AcDocRow(this.FinYear, this.DocNoTemp, this.DocRow, this.HsbCod, this.RowDsc, this.Bedehkar, this.Bestankar, this.Bookmark, this.MainDocNo, this.DocDate);
    }

    public resetModel(finYear, docNoTemp, docRow, hsbCod, rowDsc, bedehkar, bestankar, bookmark, mainDocNo, docDate): void{
        this.constructor(finYear, docNoTemp, docRow, hsbCod, rowDsc, bedehkar, bestankar, bookmark, mainDocNo, docDate);
    }
}
```

but the compiled JS, does not contains the method i wrote in 'DynamicPropertiesProvider' class:

For DynamicPropertiesProvider:

```
/**
 * Created by Hassan on 4/4/2016.
 */
var DynamicPropertiesProvider = (function () {
    function DynamicPropertiesProvider() {
        this._dynamicProperties = {};
    }
    DynamicPropertiesProvider.prototype.dynamicProperties = function () {
        return this._dynamicProperties;
    };
    return DynamicPropertiesProvider;
})();
//# sourceMappingURL=dynamicPropertiesProvider.js.map
```

For AcDocRow:

```
/**
 * Created by Hassan on 3/16/2016.
 */
var __extends = (this && this.__extends) || function (d, b) {
    for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p];
    function __() { this.constructor = d; }
    d.prototype = b === null ? Object.create(b) : (__.prototype = b.prototype, new __());
};
///<reference path="dynamicPropertiesProvider.ts"/>
var AcDocRow = (function (_super) {
    __extends(AcDocRow, _super);
    function AcDocRow(finYear, docNoTemp, docRow, hsbCod, rowDsc, bedehkar, bestankar, bookmark, mainDocNo, docDate) {
        _super.call(this); //Call Super (Parent) Class Constructor
        this.setup();
        if (finYear != undefined)
            this.FinYear = finYear;
        if (docNoTemp != undefined)
            this.DocNoTemp = docNoTemp;
        if (docRow != undefined)
            this.DocRow = docRow;
        if (hsbCod != undefined)
            this.HsbCod = hsbCod;
        if (rowDsc != undefined)
            this.RowDsc = rowDsc;
        if (bedehkar != undefined)
            this.Bedehkar = bedehkar;
        if (bestankar != undefined)
            this.Bestankar = bestankar;
        if (bookmark != undefined)
            this.Bookmark = bookmark;
        if (mainDocNo != undefined)
            this.MainDocNo = mainDocNo;
        if (docDate != undefined)
            this.DocDate = docDate;
    }
    Object.defineProperty(AcDocRow.prototype, "CompositeKey", {
        //Getters And Setters
        get: function () {
            return this.FinYear + "-" + this.DocNoTemp + "-" + this.DocRow;
        },
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
    });
    Object.defineProperty(AcDocRow.prototype, "Date", {
        get: function () {
            return ((this.DocDate) ? this.DocDate.substr(0, 4) + "/" + this.DocDate.substr(4, 2) + "/" + this.DocDate.substr(6, 2) : "");
        },
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
    });
    AcDocRow.prototype.setup = function () {
        this.FinYear = "";
        this.DocNoTemp = 0;
        this.DocRow = 0;
        this.HsbCod = "";
        this.RowDsc = "";
        this.Bedehkar = 0;
        this.Bestankar = 0;
        this.Bookmark = false;
        this.MainDocNo = 0;
        this.DocDate = "";
    };
    AcDocRow.prototype.copy = function () {
        return new AcDocRow(this.FinYear, this.DocNoTemp, this.DocRow, this.HsbCod, this.RowDsc, this.Bedehkar, this.Bestankar, this.Bookmark, this.MainDocNo, this.DocDate);
    };
    AcDocRow.prototype.resetModel = function (finYear, docNoTemp, docRow, hsbCod, rowDsc, bedehkar, bestankar, bookmark, mainDocNo, docDate) {
        this.constructor(finYear, docNoTemp, docRow, hsbCod, rowDsc, bedehkar, bestankar, bookmark, mainDocNo, docDate);
    };
    return AcDocRow;
})(DynamicPropertiesProvider);
//# sourceMappingURL=acDocRow.js.map
```

My ts compiler is the one come along with WebStrom 11.0
and i aslo set '--target es5' flag.

what should i do?

[image]

[image]

---

### **Edit due iberbeu comment:**

My Service Where i read the data from server, and then i create a AcDocRow object from them

```
app.factory("AcDocRowService",
    ["$resource",
        function ($resource) {
            //noinspection JSUnusedGlobalSymbols,JSUnusedLocalSymbols
            return $resource("/api/AcDocRows/:id:filter:param1/:param2",
                {
                    id: "@id",
                    param1: "@param1",
                    param2: "@param2",
                    filter: "@filter"
                },
                {
                    "query": {
                        method: "GET",
                        isArray: true,
                        transformResponse: function(data, header) {
                            var wrapped = angular.fromJson(data);
                            //If contains exceptions, it is not a list and should return directly without modification
                            //noinspection JSUnresolvedVariable
                            if (!wrapped.ExceptionType && !wrapped.ExceptionMessage) {
                                angular.forEach(wrapped, function (item, idx) {
                                    wrapped[idx] = new AcDocRow(
                                        wrapped[idx].FinYear,
                                        wrapped[idx].DocNoTemp,
                                        wrapped[idx].DocRow,
                                        wrapped[idx].HsbCod,
                                        wrapped[idx].RowDsc,
                                        wrapped[idx].Bedehkar,
                                        wrapped[idx].Bestankar,
                                        wrapped[idx].Bookmark,
                                        wrapped[idx].MainDocNo,
                                        wrapped[idx].DocDate
                                    );
                                });
                            }
                            return wrapped;
                        }
                    },
                    "get": {
                        method: "GET",
                        isArray: false
                    },
                    "update": {
                        method: "PUT"
                    },
                    "setBookmark":{
                        method: "PUT",
                        params:{
                            param2: "SetBookmark"
                        }
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    ]
);
```

My controller when i tell service to return data, and then i bind it to the view.

```
app.controller("IndexController", [
    "$rootScope", "$scope", "$uibModal", "$timeout", "AcDocRowService", "FinYearService",
    function ($rootScope, $scope, $uibModal, $timeout, AcDocRowService, FinYearService) {

        $scope.View = {
            SarfaslSelectionDialog: {
                ShowDialog: false,
                /**
                 * Output Result Selected Sarfasl
                 */
                SelectedSarfasl: null,
                FinYear: null,
                InitialHsbCod: null
            },
            CodeInfo: {
                LenCod: 0,
                LenK: 0,
                LenM: 0,
                LenT1: 0,
                LenT2: 0,
                LenJ: 0
            },
            OperationMode: null,
            Errors: [],
            AcDocRowList: [],
            AcDocRowFilters:{
                ShowFilters: false,
                Bookmark: null,
                FromDate: "",
                ToDate: "",
                FromDocNoTemp: null,
                ToDocNoTemp: null,
                FromPrice: null,
                ToPrice: null
            },
            AcDocRowSummery: {
                TotalResult: 0,
                CheckedResult: 0,
                UncheckedResult: 0,
                TotalDemand: 0,
                TotalDept: 0,
                CheckedDemand: 0,
                CheckedDept: 0,
                UncheckedDemand: 0,
                UncheckedDept: 0
            },
            SelectedItems: []
        };

        $scope.Events= {
            selectRow: function(row){
                if($scope.View.SelectedItems.contains(row)){
                    $scope.View.SelectedItems.remove(row);
                } else {
                    $scope.View.SelectedItems.push(row)
                }

                //MY OLD CODES WHERE I READ THE 'row' Object

                //if(! row.dynamicProperties()["selected"])
                //    row.dynamicProperties()["selected"]= true;
                //row.dynamicProperties()["selected"] = !row.dynamicProperties()["selected"];
            },
            ...
            //Where i set AcDocRowList, That i use in my View
            searchAcDocRows: function() {
                $scope.Events.openWaitDialog();

                //If Method Called On Start By $Watch, Return
                if($scope.View.SarfaslSelectionDialog.SelectedSarfasl == null){
                    return;
                }

                var sarfaslParams = $scope.View.SarfaslSelectionDialog;

                var filter = "FinYear=" + sarfaslParams.FinYear + "-HsbCod=" + sarfaslParams.SelectedSarfasl.getClearHsbCod();
                AcDocRowService.query({ filter: filter }).$promise.then(
                    function (data) {
                        $scope.Methods.resetTotals();
                        $scope.View.AcDocRowList = data;
                        $scope.Events.closeWaitDialog();
                    }, function (errorResult) {
                        $scope.View.Errors.push(new Alert("Cannot contact web server at this moment. Please try again later.", AlertType.Danger));
                        $scope.Events.closeWaitDialog();
                    }
                );
            }
            ...
        };
        ...

    }
]);
```

My View:

```
...
            <tbody>
                <tr data-ng-repeat="row in View.AcDocRowList | filter: Filters.acDocRowFilterFunction"
                    data-ng-class="{'checked-row':row.Bookmark}" data-ng-click="Events.selectRow(row)">
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="row.Bookmark" data-ng-click="Events.setBookmark(row)">
                    </td>
                    <td class="number">
                        <!--Restart Total Price-->
                        {{Methods.setTotal($index, row.Bookmark); $index | persianNumberFilter}}
                    </td>
                    <td class="number">{{row.DocNoTemp | persianNumberFilter}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <!--row.Date is a 'getter' -->
                        {{row.Date | persianNumberFilter}}
                    </td>
                    <td>{{row.RowDsc | persianNumberFilter}}</td>
                    <td class="number">{{row.Bedehkar!=0?row.Bedehkar:"" | priceFilter | persianNumberFilter}}</td>
                    <td class="number">{{row.Bestankar!=0?row.Bestankar:"" | priceFilter | persianNumberFilter}}</td>
                    <td>
                        {{Methods.getTashkhis()}}
                    </td>
                    <td class="number">
                        {{Methods.getRemains()!=0?Methods.getRemains():"" | priceFilter | persianNumberFilter}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
...
```

---

### Solved

AngularJs ngResource doesn't parse transformResponse action directly. it pass it to $http in angular core to handle it. and once the result come out. it again fold the data inside object of Resource class. that's when resource constructor do a shallow copy as it named the method. and as it's name says lot of things in the deeper level go loss, also object type get changed.

I fix the issue with updating the angular ngResource and provide with new action "transformResult", and I use it instead of transformResponse.
it perform it's job at the end before ngResource pass results to the user.

https://github.com/deadmann/code.angularjs.org/blob/master/1.4.9/angular-resource.js

I also made pull request, which I don't think so, but I hope they accept.
https://github.com/angular/code.angularjs.org/pull/35

Comment: abstract classes are only available after typescript version 1.6 Are you compiling with 1.6 or greater?

Comment: compiler version: 1.6.2 (bundled)

Comment: The compilation is fine. If your paste your code here http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/ you will get the same compilation and it works. I guess your problem is that ´row´ is not the object type you are waiting for

Comment: i modified my post, and add my angular binding information

Comment: the cod in controller and service is not typescript. so how are you sure that you pass the right types? There are 2 options: row is not of wanted type or as basarat said the files are not getting compiled in the right order

Comment: i never compiled a ts file manually or have app for that, but i do this, first i write my code, then i modify the first file, the webstrom compile it, then i modify the child, and webstrom compile that (as webstrom is aware of references, it may also recompile related things it self, but i didn't check that.)... in the end i reference JS files to my project. BTW you can see compiled version of both file in the top which i don't get any thing from them (two are ts, and other are their compiled version) ....if the compilation is wrong... then it's bug with ts came with webstrom, otherwise ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the ngResource, and made a pull request, which provide transforming latest result from a service.
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/14381

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have a module ordering problem. I recommend not using `outFile` and looking into using a module pattern e.g. commonjs : https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/out.md

Comment: so you mean my AcDocRow need recompiling? i gave it a try, and it didn't worked. or you mean something else

Comment: I mean the order if compiled JavaScript might be wrong. E.g. something like `console.log(foo); var foo =123` instead of `var foo =123;console.log(foo); ` might be happening.

Comment: i tried that (first i compiled the abstract, and then the inherited class)... not working... and inside the js file... it gave error before, so i put the parent file in the beginning of bundling queue